# Why are maps/google maps not showing the street number?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, maps

I am currently opening maps and google maps when someone clicks on "Navigate to that address".

```
  const openMaps = () => {
    const scheme = Platform.select({ ios: "maps:0,0?q=", android: "geo:0,0?q=" })
    //@ts-ignore
    const latLng = `${address.latitude},${address.longitude}`
    const label = name
    const url = Platform.select({
      ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
      android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`,
    })

    Linking.openURL(url)
  }
```

It is working perfectly fine, the only thing is that it is not showing the street number. When I enter the coordinates on this site: [Reverse Geocoding Convert Lat Long to Address](https://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html)

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a sample that does not show the street number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was actually removing the label. Now it works fine.